# Add a new field in Mongo object and initialize with the value from another field, in one query

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a new field to all the mongo objects in one of my collections using one mongo query. This new field will be initialized to the value of another field in its object.

Say the Mongo object is like:

```
{
    "_id" : "24a1aefe-7242-4104-b6a9-8f9993b22019",
    "attributes" : {
        "product name" : "Duracell Aa Batteries 2 Pc"
    },
    "sku_id" : "4_5",
    "state" : "ENABLED"
}
```

I want to make all the mongo objects like:

```
{
    "_id" : "24a1aefe-7242-4104-b6a9-8f9993b22019",
    "attributes" : {
        "product name" : "Duracell Aa Batteries 2 Pc"
    },
    "sku_id" : "4_5",
    "new_sku_id": "4_5"
    "state" : "ENABLED"
}
```

I was able to do this using pymongo, but that requires multiple update queries to be fired to the mongo server and works in a for loop.

Is there a single mongo query that can solve my problem? Please help.

I am using the following mongo query which is not working:

> db.skus.update({},{"$set":{"new_sku_id":"$sku_id"}},{multi:true})

But this is not working. It is resulting in the following mongo object:

```
{
    "_id" : "24a1aefe-7242-4104-b6a9-8f9993b22019",
    "attributes" : {
        "product name" : "Duracell Aa Batteries 2 Pc"
    },
    "sku_id" : "4_5",
    "new_sku_id": "$sku_id"
    "state" : "ENABLED"
}
```

**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to other fields in `update` statement but you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) to generate that field and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) to rewrite existing collection with the output of aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            new_sku_id: "$sku_id"
        }
    },
    {  $out: "collection" }
])
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this updates the mongo object with `new_sku_id` as `$sku_id` and not the value in `sku_id`

Comment: Awesome!! The issue here is that a new collection would be created and then I have to rename the new collection. What are the repercussions of doing the following: `db.skus.aggregate([ { $addFields: { external_sku_id: "$sku_id" } }, { $out: "skus" } ])` ??

Comment: @User_Targaryen you can run it directly on the same collection, please take a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html#replace-existing-collection

Answer (score 0):

In mongo collection you can run this. This will take time depend on the number documents in the collection.

```
db.getCollection('skus').find({}).forEach(function(obj){
 db.getCollection('skus').update({_id:obj._id},{$set:{new_sku_id: obj.sku_id}})
})
```

Comment: this is same as the for loop approach I did, using pymongo. The above will still fire multiple update queries instead of just one bulk call.